# What is the author trying to explain here?

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness

From [Aaronson's 2006 lecture notes for PHYS$771$](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec3.html):

> ... Why the Incompleteness Theorem doesn't contradict the Completeness
> Theorem? The easiest way to do this is probably through an example.
> Consider the "self-hating theory" PA+Not(Con(PA)), or Peano Arithmetic
> plus the assertion of its own inconsistency. We know that if PA is
> consistent, then this strange theory must be consistent as well --
> since otherwise PA would prove its own consistency, which the
> Incompleteness Theorem doesn't allow. It follows, by the Completeness
> Theorem, that PA+Not(Con(PA)) must have a model. But what could such a
> model possibly look like? In particular, what you happen if, within
> that model, you just asked to see the proof that PA was inconsistent?
>
> I'll tell you what would happen: the axioms would tell you that proof
> of PA's inconsistency is encoded by a positive integer X. And then you
> would say, "but what is X?" And the axioms would say, "X." And you
> would say, "But what is X, as an ordinary positive integer?"
>
> "No, no, no! Talk to the axioms."
>
> "Alright, is X greater or less than 10<sup>500,000</sup>?"
>
> "Greater." (The axioms aren't stupid: they know that if they said
> "smaller", then you could simply try every smaller number and verify
> that none of them encode a proof of PA's inconsistency.)
>
> "Alright then, what's X+1?"
>
> "Y."
>
> And so on. The axioms will keep cooking up fictitious numbers to
> satisfy your requests, and assuming that PA itself is consistent,
> you'll never be able to trap them in an inconsistency. The point of
> the Completeness Theorem is that the whole infinite set of fictitious
> numbers the axioms cook up will constitute a model for PA -- just not
> the usual model (i.e., the ordinary positive integers)! If we insist
> on talking about the usual model, then we switch from the domain of
> the Completeness Theorem to the domain of the Incompleteness Theorem.

1. What is meant by "self-halting theory"? And how is PA+Not(Con(PA)) consistent?
2. What is the author trying to say by the *fictitious* number argument where Axioms respond by saying X, etc. Why would I *want* to ask to see the proof of PA's inconsistency?

Comment: You should [cite the original source](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec3.html).

Comment: I'd like the source for this too please, can you edit it into the question?

Comment: @TenO'Four I've gone ahead and edited in the source myself. To the OP, you should do this yourself in the future.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, thanks 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Throughout I'll assume that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent.*

---

### Re: (1):

"Self-halting theory" is just a bit of colorful language. "Self-*doubting*" would be more appropriate in my opinion (or maybe "halting" is a typo for "hating"?). Regardless, it's not worth focusing on.

The real question is why $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}$ is consistent. This is a beautiful consequence of the second incompleteness theorem:

- If $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}\vdash\perp$, the deduction theorem would give us $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \neg \mathsf{Con(PA)}\rightarrow\perp$, or equivalently $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash\neg (\neg \mathsf{Con(PA))}.$$
- But that's just a funny way of saying "$\mathsf{PA}\vdash \mathsf{Con(PA)}$." And we know *that* can't happen, by Godel, unless $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent.

Put another way, "$T$ doesn't prove $A$" is always equivalent to "$T+\neg A$ is consistent." Here we're using $T=\mathsf{PA}$ and $A=\mathsf{Con(PA)}$.

---

### Re: (2):

The point is that the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (not a typo - quite different from the incompleteness theorem, the terminology overlap is quite unfortunate) says that any consistent theory has a model. In particular, per the section above the theory $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}$ must have a model, $M$.

At first glance this seems weird: $M$ must think that part of its own behavior is contradictory! Personally I think this is very worth looking into ("Why would I *want* to ask to see the proof of PA's inconsistency?"), and the corresponding portion of the argument simply seeks to demystify it.

The punchline of course is that $\neg\mathsf{Con(PA)}$ is an *existential* statement, and the things in $M$ which ($M$ thinks) witness the truth of this statement are not actually standard natural numbers (that is, not in the range of the unique embedding $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow M$). So there's no contradiction between $M$ thinking that there is a number coding a contradiction in $\mathsf{PA}$, and there not actually being such a number in reality.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you recheck the last statement under Re: (1)?

Comment: @Ajax Whoops, good catch, fixed.

Comment: What is *happening* then? If these non-standard numbers do not exist in reality...what is the basis of there being "...no contradiction between  thinking that there is a number coding a contradiction in , and **there not actually being such a number in reality**" ...whatever "thinking" is supposed to mean here...?

Comment: @Ajax Don't read too much into the word "thinking," it's just language I'm using to try to make things less confusing. Here's a concrete example of a simpler phenomenon: if we let $M$ be the ordered semiring of polynomials in one variable $\alpha$ with integer coefficients which (are zero or) have positive leading term, we get a model of Robinson arithmetic + $$(\dagger)\quad \exists x\forall y(y+y\not=x\wedge y+y\not=x+1)$$ (take $x=\alpha$). So this $M$ "thinks" that there is a number which is not even or odd. But of course, in reality (= $\mathbb{N}$) every number is even or odd.

Comment: Okay, but if I press on "...and there not actually being such a number in reality" ...where does that leave us? Can I interpret this model M as composed of "garbage" (in technical sense)? ...enough garbage to get "work done"?

Comment: @Ajax "where does that leave us?" I'm not really sure what that means. "Can I interpret this model M as composed of "garbage" (in technical sense)? ...enough garbage to get "work done"?" Probably? That's pretty vague, so I'm not sure. The point is that any model $M$ of $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}$ has a "standard part" and a "nonstandard part," and the fact that $M\models\neg\mathsf{Con(PA)}$ amounts entirely to a fact about the "nonstandard part." Is that "garbage?" I don't know, it depends on what you consider garbage, but it's certainly not "genuine natural numbers."

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the same source, Aaronson quotes Turing, "*If we want a machine to be intelligent, it can't also be infallible. There are theorems that say almost exactly that.*" I don't know how to construct a question around that in Math.SE. Perhaps if you could provide some explanation as to how G'Thms relate to Turing's remark. Will add to this question if required.

Comment: @Ajax "I don't know how to construct a question around that in Math.SE." ... OK? Why do you *need* to construct a question around that? For what it's worth, not every line of expository text needs systematic exegesis; the important point is the actual mathematics, and I would focus on understanding that rather than over-emphasizing the specific language used in explaining it.

Comment: "or maybe "halting" is a typo for "hating"" - considering that the quoted text uses "hating", and "halting" only appears in question 1 after the quote, "halting" is definitely an error. It's supposed to be "hating".

Comment: @NoahSchweber What will happen if my computer implements +¬()?

Comment: @Ajax What does it even *mean* for a computer to "implement $\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathsf{Con(PA)}$"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber set up a Turing Machine corresponding to the formal system?

Comment: @Ajax OK, what does it mean for a Turing machine to "correspond to" a formal system?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Only allowing specific transition rules plus a tape with axioms printed on it... (Isn't TM simply a human *calculating* within Formal system ?)

Comment: @Ajax This is all too vague to answer so far. *Which* specific transition rules are allowed? What sort of correspondence do you have in mind? Put another way, what exactly is this machine *doing* - for example, are you just asking for a machine which searches through $\mathsf{PA}+\neg \mathsf{Con(PA)}$-proofs? (Meanwhile I'm not sure what your parenthetical means.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, proving all provable theorems - isn't that what TM does (I'm asking)? And isn't that equivalent to a human calculating in strictest sense?

Comment: @Ajax Different TMs do different things. I'm not sure what "equivalent to a human calculating in strictest sense" means, so I can't comment on that. In this case what you'll get is for example a machine which successfully finds a proof of (appropriately coded) the statement "This machine will eventually find a proof of $0=1$," but never actually finds a proof of "$0=1$." Basically, this computer will be wrong in exactly the way the theory $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Self-hating" theory is just the author's whimsical term for a theory like $\mathrm{PA} + \lnot(\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA}))$ that asserts the inconsistency of one of its subtheories. If $\mathrm{PA} + \lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$ were inconsistent, we could derive a contradiction from $\mathrm{PA} + \lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$, which would mean that $\mathrm{PA}$ would be able to prove $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$, contradicting the second incompleteness theorem. (I am assuming throughout that $\mathrm{PA}$ is actually consistent.)
2. The second point is that as we now know that $\mathrm{PA} + \lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$ is consistent, the completeness theorem tells us that it must have a model. It is then surely natural to wonder what that model could look like. It is not hard to see that any model of a theory that extends $\mathrm{PA}$ includes a copy of the natural numbers with the usual arithmetic operations - let's call the numbers in that copy the *standard* natural numbers. But what $\lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$ actually says is that there is a number $X$ that encodes a proof of $0 \neq 0$. That number can't be a standard natural number, otherwise it would encode a proof in $\mathrm{PA}$ of $0 \neq 0$. So we conclude, working back through the definition of $\mathrm{Con}$, that the model includes a host of non-standard natural numbers  which conspire to give the illusion that $0\neq 0$ has a proof.

Comment: Let me ask...you use the word "conspire" only from our perspective...? That for model M, everything may mean entirely different....and perhaps not so controversial?

Comment: By "conspire", I mean that the arithmetic on the non-standard numbers makes $X$ look like it encodes a finite set of valid inference steps that prove $0 \neq 0$. However, because $X$ is non-standard, if we tried to unwind the definitions of our encoding to find that finite set of inference steps, the process would never terminate.

Comment: ...but process would end, if say magically, I know the encoding for non-standard numbers...?

Comment: No the process would not end: if it did, $X$ must have been standard to start with. Note the encoding I am talking about is the encoding of proofs as numbers, as used to define the predicate $\mathrm{Con}$. For a given model, the process I am talking about is fully determined: there is nothing that any magical extra information could do to make it terminate.